# Checking if function is not null using ampersand

Tags: javascript, convention

I found some strange usages (imho) of `if` shortcut in some `JavaScript` project.

I think this is really bad convention, but I can't find any "good practise" or some mentor's article that gives me unequivocal proof.

Example of usage:

```
function (someFuncParam) {
   ...
   someFuncParam && someFuncParam();
}
```

I would fix it to something like:

```
function (someFuncParam) {
   ...
   if (typeof (someFuncParam) === 'function')
      someFuncParam();
}
```

Am I right? Or I'm missing something (asking because, some people of my company tell me that it's nothing wrong in writing code in the first way...).

Comment: That's the correct way to do it, even better, if it fails to be a function, throw a `TypeError`, fail-fast rather than creating a bug(I am talking about the second approach)

Comment: `someFuncParam instanceof Function && someFuncParam()` :P

Comment: __The first usage is better.__ Since the only way to throw an error in this situation is in the development phase, why would you avoid the error? If one function was not given let throw the error `"someFuncParam" is not a function` in the console.

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes Not avoiding errors is better for you?

Comment: If some function expect an argument to be a function, and you forgot to send it, it is much better to throw to the console `"argument" is not a function` rather than silently failing.

Comment: No, no. I think in this case it is intended to avoid the errors, because `someFuncParam` is an optional parameter (in my project, I forgot to mention about it, my bad).